# pull-request-review-request-event send webhooks as many times as the number of reviewers

Tags: github, webhooks, pull-request, github-webhook

I implemented a server that recevies webhook from github and forward it to Google Chat.
All other webhooks work well. But, if someone opened a pull-request with multiple reviewers, Github sends webhook(triggered by pull-request-request-review-event) as many as the number of reviewers.

Let's say there are four reviewers assigned to a PR, then GitHub sends pull-request-request-review webhook four times.
As a result, it calls the server i implements four times and the server forward it to Google Chat four times, which is not the way i want it to work like.

Is there any way i can make GitHub send only one time of webhook for pull-request-request-reviewer event?

Comment: Was this issue fixed? I have the same issue with GitHub repo connected to Tekton. Appreciate, your valuable thoughts.